# FlashDevelop + Air - iPhone 5 size

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I export to iOS using the mobile packager built into FlashDevelop.

It supports most of the devices (ios and droid) but it does not come up with
iPhone 5 testing size.

In order to set the device, Run.bat has to be edited like:

```
::set SCREEN_SIZE=NexusOne
::set SCREEN_SIZE=iPhoneRetina
set SCREEN_SIZE=iPad
::set SCREEN_SIZE=iPadRetina
::set SCREEN_SIZE=iPhone
```

But when I enter iPhone5 I get an error.

Are there any solutions since the new screen size is important?

Mirza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
set SCREEN_SIZE=iPhone5Retina
```

you can also see some other options here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-6fa6d7e0128cca93d31-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Capabilities.screenResolutionX
Capabilities.screenResolutionY
```

to catch the resolution on whichever device your app is executed on.

you might have to type

```
<requestedDisplayResolution>standard</requestedDisplayResolution>
```

in the App Descriptor XML file.